# How to import and use another package

Tags: java, android

I have my main project and I have created another on the side. The new one simply listens for a button click and then runs methods to update a users twitter status.

What I am unable to do at the moment is use this in my original project. I could copy the code into every .java file but that would be excessive.

What would be a better way to accomplish this and activate the onclick listener.

Answer (score 1):

If the library is provided as a jar file, then place it in the /libs folder in your project.

If the library is itself an android project, read up on [Android Library Projects](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html)

If the problem is simply "How do you import a package?", [Read this.](http://leepoint.net/notes-java/language/10basics/import.html)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am now trying to run the method buttonSend() and no matter where I place it in the class it comes back with it is undefined

Comment: I don't know that method. If you want to talk about code, please edit your question and paste in the code.

Comment: @SkyKelsey Your second link ("Read this") is currently is a 404 dead-end.  It needs a **www.** in front of the URL to work properly.

Comment: @SkyKelsey  Actually I think that link is just dead now.  I'm guessing [this link has the article](http://www.leepoint.net/language/10basics/import.html) you were referencing.